# Select N Rows With Mixed Values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with columns like

```
insertTimeStamp, port, data
1              , 20  , 'aaa'
2              , 20  , 'aba'
3              , 20  , '3aa'
4              , 20  , 'aab'
2              , 21  , 'aza'
5              , 21  , 'aha'
8              , 21  , 'aaa'
15             , 22  , '2aa'
```

Now I need *N* Rows (Say 4) from that table, ordered asc by `insertTimeStamp`.
But if possible, I want to get them from different `port`s.

So the result should be:

```
1              , 20  , 'aaa'
2              , 20  , 'aba'
2              , 21  , 'aza'
15             , 22  , '2aa'
```

If there are not enough different values in `port` I would like select the remaining ones with the lowest `insertTimeStamp`.

Comment: as per your criteria, the 4th row in the result should be `3              , 20  , '3aa'`?

Comment: @vkp I dont think so. Current desire output look ok.  Select first insertTimeStamp from each port and then select from the rest with the lowest TimeStamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d14d/5)**

As you can see I create a `group_id` so `group_id = 1` will be the smaller `TimeStamp` for each port

The second field is `time_id` so in the `ORDER BY` after I select all the `1` bring all the `2,3,4` for any port.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
         SELECT *, 
            row_number() over (partition by "port" order by "insertTimeStamp") group_id,
            row_number() over (order by "insertTimeStamp") time_id
         FROM Table1 T
   ) as T
   ORDER BY CASE 
               WHEN group_id = 1 THEN group_id
               ELSE time_id
            END
   LIMIT 4
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| insertTimeStamp | port | data | group_id | time_id |
|-----------------|------|------|----------|---------|
|               1 |   20 |  aaa |        1 |       1 |
|               2 |   21 |  aza |        1 |       3 |
|              15 |   22 |  2aa |        1 |       8 |
|               2 |   20 |  aba |        2 |       2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number():

```
select *
from (
    select insertTimeStamp, port, data
    from (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by port order by insertTimeStamp) rn
        from a_table
        ) alias
    order by rn, insertTimeStamp
    limit 4
    ) alias
order by 1, 2;

 inserttimestamp | port | data 
-----------------+------+------
               1 |   20 | aaa
               2 |   20 | aba
               2 |   21 | aza
              15 |   22 | 2aa
(4 rows)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c25ea/1)

Comment: I tought about this one. For this sample data may work, But if you have a `rn = 2` and `time = 15` will show before `rn = 3` and `time = 3`  and you can miss it because `limit 4`

Comment: I do not think so, can you show me a fiddle? And what it `time`??

Comment: Sorry I mean `inserttimestamp`  Here [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85ecc/1)  You can see 6th element isnt the smaller one.

Comment: Thanks. This is intentional, even distribution of excess rows for each group in order by `inserttimestamp`. Perhaps it is a problem of interpretation, as the assumptions are not entirely clear.